# What is the best way to store user profiles and logins?

Tags: mysql, users, logins

I need to store user profiles and logins. Is the best way to do that to have a table for logins (email, username, and password) and a separate table for their profile/info (e.g. their progress in something)? I am using MySQL if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if tables relate one-to-one, put both sets of columns in a single table.  (There are exceptions, but I don't see one here.)

On the other hand, "progress" sounds like some type of log?  That is, there might be lots of rows for each user?  Then you must have 2 tables, one with user info, one with 'progress'.

The user table would have a `user_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY` and the log table would have an `INDEX(user_id, datetime)` or something like that.  (I am assuming there is a datetime/timestamp column in the log.)